# Table lines needing removed

Tags: tables

I have a table that i am currently trying to put in my thesis however as you can see there are some unnecessary vertical line segments present in the "Strain" row. Is there an easy way to remove the part of thevertical line that is on the right of the "strain"?

Thanks!

[image: Table]

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\caption*{Critical Shear Stress Values}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c| c| c|c|}
\centering
 & Strain \\
\hline
Ratio & MG1655 & AD26 & AD104  \\
\hline
5:1 & 3.24 &1.85 & 0.92  \\
10:1 & 6.01 & 2.77 & 2.31 \\
20:1 & 6.48 & 3.24 & 2.77 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you're trying to obtain is not quite clear. Is it a two-lined header  in column 2, per chance?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bernard. Basically in the top row with the word "Strain" in it i'd like to remove the horizontal lines in that row and have the word "Strain" above "AD26". I'm not sure about how to remove only parts of the lines though (if its even easily possible)?

Comment: You can  do that with a single row and the `makecell` package, using the `\makecell[b]{Strain\\ MG1655}` code for the column head.

Comment: I think you mean remove vertical lines ( | ) not remove horizontal line ( ---) ?

Comment: Yes "vertical", not horizontal! Sorry!

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{Strain}` or perhaps `\multicolumn{3}{c}{Strain}`

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]% only use ! in exceptional cases [h!]
\caption{Critical Shear Stress Values}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c| c| c|c|}
% this does nothing here \centering
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Strain} \\
\hline
Ratio & MG1655 & AD26 & AD104  \\
\hline
5:1 & 3.24 &1.85 & 0.92  \\
10:1 & 6.01 & 2.77 & 2.31 \\
20:1 & 6.48 & 3.24 & 2.77 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Although I'd advise looking at the booktabs package documentation which somewhat agressively (but usefully:-) advises against using vertical rules in tables.

Comment: I'd think `\multicolumn{1}{c}{}` would be better than `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}`

Answer (score 2):

You may liked:

[image]

With use of the `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=0.3\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Critical Shear Stress Values}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{% style definition
    vline{1} = {2-Z}{solid},
    vline{2-Z} = {1-Z}{solid},
    hline{1} = {2-Z}{solid},
    hline{2,3,Z} = {1-Z}{solid},
            }
        & \SetCell[c=3]{c}  Strain  \\
Ratio   & MG1655    & AD26 & AD104  \\
5:1     & 3.24      & 1.85 & 0.92   \\
10:1    & 6.01      & 2.77 & 2.31   \\
20:1    & 6.48      & 3.24 & 2.77   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `booktabs`-based version:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Critical Shear Stress Values}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{r@{:}lccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Ratio} &\multicolumn{3}{c}{Strain} \\
\cmidrule{3-5}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{} & MG1655 & AD26 & AD104  \\
\midrule
5&1 & 3.24 &1.85 & 0.92  \\
10&1 & 6.01 & 2.77 & 2.31 \\
20&1 & 6.48 & 3.24 & 2.77 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For this table, instead of splitting the cells with the ratios, I would just set them all flush-right since it's always 1 to the right of the colon.